# UITableView will not resize after UITextField becomes first responder

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios5, scroll, uitextfield

I have two Scenes in my Storyboard that are nearly identical.  Both are UITableViewControllers.  Both have header and footer views.  The header views have a UISearchBar and the footer views have a UIView that contains a UITextField.  Each have only one prototype cell.  One is prototyped as a "Basic" cell and the other is prototyped as "Right Detail" cell.

Here's the problem.  When I click the UITextField in the footer view on the first scene, the table resizes automatically so that the bottom of the table is at the top of the keyboard. This allows me to scroll the table up so the footer view shows and the user is able to see what they're typing.  The other scene will not automatically resize the UITableView so the UITableView cannot scroll the footer view to where it can be seen and the UITextField is hidden under the keyboard.  I can't even manually scroll the table far enough since the footer is always at the bottom of the UITableView.

A little added info.  The scene that works has many rows of data while the one that doesn't work only has a couple.  I tried adding a number of rows until the table had enough to enable scrolling and it doesn't fix the problem.

I have checked everything I can think of and I can't see anything that would allow one of the views to let the UITableView to automatically resize to work with the keyboard and the other not.  I must have overlooked something but I can't seem to find it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Rob

Answer (score 2):

I thought this problem was caused by copy-and-pasting from one view to another, but I had the same problem once I'd (in theory) fixed it.

The answer for me turned out to be simple: I hadn't called `[super viewWillAppear:animated]` in my UITableViewController subclass' `viewWillAppear:` implementation.  Make sure you've got a call to the superclass' method and hopefully the problem will go away.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing the frame of the tableview is not being resized to the smaller size in the second case.

Print out the frame and content sizes in both the cases once its loaded, that should help you see if there is an issue.